# Unexpected T_IF no idea what i am doing wrong

Tags: php, html

```
<td>              
<div style="display: none"><?=$pass = $myRs['Pass'];?></div>
<?= if ($pass == 1)
{
print "Ja";
}
else
{
print "Nee";
}
</td>
```

I'm trying to put the result from an array into a variable (which keeps getting printed for some reason). But now i keep getting unexpected T_IF

Comment: Replace "<?=" by "<?php" and close the php tag at then end.

Comment: No, insert close tag "?>" and remove short echo tag("=")

Comment: The problem is the <?= open tag: <?= is a special short open tag meaning open PHP __and__ echo all rolled into one, you can't embed an `if` in an echo

Comment: The missing ?> close tag is simply an additional problem

Comment: May I ask why my question is downvoted? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` means `echo` the string followed by `=` in PHP5, so it is throwing you unexpected `T_IF` error, so you need to use `<?php` or `<?` if shorthand is enabled. Also you are missing out a closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a = symbol after php open tag and also You forgot to close php close tag. change it to this

```
<td>              
<div style="display: none"><?=$pass = $myRs['Pass'];?></div>
<?php if ($pass == 1)
{
print "Ja";
}
else
{
print "Nee";
}
?>
</td>
```